# right rank(M) $\neq$ left rank(M)

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

In Artin, *Galois Theory*, we can prove that for any field $k$ the right column rank (noted RC, which is equal to the maximum number of independant columns with multiplication from right) is equal to the left row rank (LR), to the right row rank and to the left row rank.
Assume now $k$ is a skew field. Them we only have the equality $RC = LR$, and similary $LC = RR$.

> Is there a concrete exemple of a matrix $M \in \mathcal M_{n,m}(k)$  such that $$ RC \neq LC ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x,y \in k$ be such that $xy \ne yx$. Consider the matrix 
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ y & xy \end{pmatrix} $$
As 
$$ \binom x{xy} = x \cdot \binom 1y $$
$A$'s left column rank is 1.

On the other side $A$ for no $z \in k$ we have 
$$ \binom x{xy} = \binom 1y \cdot z  = \binom z{yz} $$
As this would imply $z=x$ and hence $xy = yz = yx$. So $A$'s right column rank is 2.

Comment: Oh, it was simple but very nice, thanks !